# Reuse Javascript TypedArray (e.g. Uint32Array)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm using [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) in a Javascript game to send data between the client (running in a browser) and the server (running node.js). I can send messages back and forth no problem but I'm interested in reusing my typed arrays rather than creating a new one each time I send a message.

Here's my sendMessage code:

```
function sendMessage(socket, data) {

    // data is JSON
    var encoded = BISON.encode(data);
    if (socket.isBinary) {
        var len = encoded.length,
            bytes = new Uint32Array(len);

        for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            bytes[i] = encoded.charCodeAt(i);
        }
    }

    if (server && socket.isBinary) {
        socket.send(bytes, { binary: true, mask: false });
    } else {
        socket.send(encoded);
    }

}
```

and here's my readMessage code:

```
function readMessage(data) {

    if (data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
        var bytes = new Uint32Array(data);
        data = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytes);
    }
    var message = JSON.stringify(BISON.decode(data));
    return JSON.parse(message);
}
```

Each time I send a message I create a new Uint32Array, initializing it to the length of the message I intend to send. Rather than create a new array each time I'd like reuse this array for each message.

My current line of thought on this is to determine my `maxMessageSize` and initialize the array with this length. `maxMessageSize` would be the largest allowed message that one could send over the socket.

### The Question(s)

Most messages are not likely to be *exactly* `maxMessageSize` in size. In these cases would I need to pad the length of the message with some value (`null`?). When reading the value on the other end of the socket how would I know when this padding began?

In writing all of this out another question has occurred to me: is this even worth the effort?

### Libraries Used

- [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) for websockets in node.js
- [BISON](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/BiSON.js) for binary encoding of json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to change the length of a [*Uint*Array*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/Uint32Array) once it has been constructed, you can only get sub arrays from them.

Any padding would have to be done with 32-bit integers, if you tried to use `null`, `ToInt(null)` is `0` so you'd have a `0` in that entry. If you wanted to pad like this, you'd need to pass some length value (either first or last entry in array), which you'd need to look at on the received end to know when to trim the data and would mean `maxMessageSize` is one less.

Using a subarray might be what you want though, construct your max-length array, fill it up, then use `.subarray(0, len)` to get the actual array you want. I'm not sure if this has any advantages over constructing a new one each time.

Comment: Forgot to put the bit about not being able to change typed array's length. That's definitely not gonna happen, hence all the `maxMessageSize` and padding stuff. I like your suggestion. I'll give it a try and do some benchmarking to see what performs best.

Comment: I created [this sample](https://github.com/NoobsArePeople2/js-profiling/blob/master/typed-arrays/index.html) to put things to the test. Both tests are run for 10,000 iterations in Chrome. When creating a new array each loop it took 23.057ms. Reusing the array each loop took 11.566ms. Reuse is definitely faster but creating new arrays isn't exactly slow.

Comment: You should have profiled the `readReusedUint32Array` too, because if `.subarray` is much faster than `new Uint32Array`, rather than storing `len` in `arr[0]` and sending the whole thing, you could save yourself a little bandwidth by subarray-ing before sending. This would also mean you're not re-sending non-overwritten data from a previous invocation (which may be sensitive?).

Comment: Additionally, now I'm thinking of security etc, make sure you **do** have new instances of `Uint32Array`s for asynchronous things (race conditions are always bad).

Comment: Good call on profiling `subarray`. Will add that later. Are you thinking have a pool of arrays to work through so the array doesn't get overwritten if a message comes in while I'm reading a message?

Comment: I didn't mean a "pool of arrays" (that just defers race conditions until heavy load) but yes to the latter; You don't want your array's entries to be overwritten between setting them and sending them, but there is a possible race condition there (say it is invoked asynchronously twice very quickly). It is fine to re-use within a "thread" but you shouldn't share the same array across "threads" when there is a possibility of such a conflict.

Comment: I've updated the sample with a `subarray` test. It's definitely quite a bit faster than the "new array" test but I notice that it's fluctuates a fair bit. In the end I think making a new array seems like it will perform fine for me. It's nice to know I have other options should that change.